# How to format multiline string in JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to POST JSON data to a server-side handler, the expected json object include a json string, the json value is a multiline string. When I POST is as is I get the formatting exception from the server.

Heres is the payload;

```
{
  "payload": "
 {
            "patient": {
                            "patient.family_name": "Samuel",
                            "patient.given_name": "Owino",
                            "patient.county": "Kilawonk",
                            "patient.location": "Mutwapa",
                            "patient.sub_location": "Kilawonta",
                            "patient.village": "Kilanoi",
                            "patient.phone_number": "0706906138",
                            "patient.medical_record_number": "123456789",
                            "patient.other_identifier_type": "KENYAN NATIONAL ID NUMBER",
                            "patient.other_identifier_value": "32332271",
                            "patient.confirm_identifier_value": "32332271",
                            "patient.sex": "M",
                            "patient.birthdate_estimated": "..."
            },
            "tmp": {
                            "tmp.birthdate_type": "age",
                            "tmp.age_in_years": "21"
            },
            "encounter": {
                            "encounter.location_id": "84",
                            "encounter.provider_id_select": "3356-3",
                            "encounter.provider_id": "3356-3",
                            "encounter.encounter_datetime": "06-11-2017"
            }
}",
  "display": " ",
  "uuid": "             597ec410-996f-494c-ae46-ebb78363f6b1"
}
```

The server reponse is as follows

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "[Could not read JSON: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-
CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string 
value\n at [Source: 
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@27811c6e; line: 2, column: 
28]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Illegal 
unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash 
to be included in string value\n at [Source: 
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@27811c6e; line: 2, column: 
28]]",
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: The exception message indicates that the JSON parser thinks that you have a carriage-return character embedded *in a value*.  Although the overall JSON string is multi-line, it does not appear that you intend to have any multiline values.  You do, however, have what appears to be a stray quotation mark on the fourth line from the end -- if that's in the actual payload then it might well be responsible for your error.

Comment: Can you highlight the stray quotation mark, please

Comment: @samuelowino you don't have a stray quotation mark, close to the end you're closing the intended string, but you must escape the quotation marks in your string that contains json.

Comment: look at fourth line from bottom

Comment: If payload takes a String value - the special characters inside like quote shoudl be escaped.

Comment: @samuelowino, I have assumed that you mean for the value of the top-level `"payload"` attribute to be a map, in which case I characterized the problem incompletely.  Others have explained it better, and also have covered the alternative in which you really want the value to be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think about escaping the **"** character in your string, otherwise the parser will think that the string end when it encounters the next matching **"**.

To escape, use a backslash **\**, like this:

`"payload": "{\"escaped\":\"value\"}"`

It can be a bit tricky to understand at first, but [json.org](http://json.org/) has a really nice explanation of how to create valid json.

Comment: Do I need to do this for every character in the string

Comment: @samuelowino yes, you do. JSON doesn't have support for multiline strings. But usually you generate json via code. Which should be able to create the intended json for you.

Comment: @samuelowino also as other people have suggested, maybe you don't have to wrap the value in "payload" as string, it is valid json that you're posting. It would be easier to code the server so that it can handle the json directly. But that assumes that you have control over the server.

Comment: @samuelowino if my answer helped you, could you please accept it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
"payload": "
```

is wrong. remove the `""` around the object that holds `patient`

Comment: Jack the patient, in this case, is just part of a string that is the value of the key payload.

Answer (score 1):

you have some invalid json in the payload, the string <"payload":, "> should read <"payload":, > and you need to also remove the " at the end of json in the way you build this up. check this uding JSONLint.

valid json below

```
   {
"payload": {
    "patient": {
        "patient.family_name": "Samuel",
        "patient.given_name": "Owino",
        "patient.county": "Kilawonk",
        "patient.location": "Mutwapa",
        "patient.sub_location": "Kilawonta",
        "patient.village": "Kilanoi",
        "patient.phone_number": "0706906138",
        "patient.medical_record_number": "123456789",
        "patient.other_identifier_type": "KENYAN NATIONAL ID NUMBER",
        "patient.other_identifier_value": "32332271",
        "patient.confirm_identifier_value": "32332271",
        "patient.sex": "M",
        "patient.birthdate_estimated": "..."
    },
    "tmp": {
        "tmp.birthdate_type": "age",
        "tmp.age_in_years": "21"
    },
    "encounter": {
        "encounter.location_id": "84",
        "encounter.provider_id_select": "3356-3",
        "encounter.provider_id": "3356-3",
        "encounter.encounter_datetime": "06-11-2017"
    }
},
"display": " ",
"uuid": "             597ec410-996f-494c-ae46-ebb78363f6b1"
```

}